# Clarification on index type query operator and extends keyword

Tags: typescript

I was going over the documentation on Advanced Types in Typescript (found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and it mentioned the Index Query Operator and gave the following as an example:

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, names: K[]): T[K][] {
  return names.map(n => o[n]);
}
```

I understand how `keyof` produces a union of all known public property names on object `T` but I don't exactly understand what role the `extends` plays.  I get that it's saying that `K` must be a valid property of `T` but why is `extends` used and not something else?  Also, is it possible to extend unions in Typescript or is this more of a semantic specific to generics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword `extends`, in this context, is a way to add a constraint on a type parameter.

Given this simple example, you will see the compiler only allows you to pass in objects that conform to the `Person` interface:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
}

function logAndReturnPerson<T extends Person>(person: T) {
    console.log(person.name);
    return person;
}

// ok
const result1 = logAndReturnPerson<Person>({ name: "David" });
// not ok, string does not satisfy constraint of Person
const result2 = logAndReturnPerson<string>("");
```

In your example, `K extends keyof T` means that `K` is constrained to `keyof T`. In other words, this means what you thought—`K` is a string that is constrained to be a property name of `T`.

Yes, this is a semantic specific to generics. Note that it's possible to use a union type in a constraint.

Comment: As a follow up question, is there more in the Typescript documentation that discusses this?  I think some additional wording would clear up any confusion; although it might be only my understanding that was limited.

Comment: @Willwsharp look at the section on "generic constraints": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html